# Type graphql - set createUnionType as InputType

Tags: typegraphql

I'm using `type-graphql` framework and I've configured a union type like so:

```
export const ActionUnion = createUnionType({
  name: 'ActionUnion',
  types: () => [CreateAction, UpdateAction, DeleteAction],
});
```

And I want to use it as my mutation input.
But when I run the service I get an error saying:

`Cannot determine GraphQL input type for userActions`

Is there a way to configure unionType to be InputType as well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in GraphQL spec, unions are only for object types. You can't have union input.